# jQuery - on custom event complete

Tags: jquery, events, plugins, listener

I created a custom lightbox plugin and I need to create a custom event/listenner when a action complete asynchronously.
My aim is to destroy/unset video/iframe source when I close the lightbox or go to next/prev items in order to prevent errors (specially on IE).

For example I have I created this script:

```
$.Lightbox = function() {

    var el;

    function init() {
        /*** do some stuff ***/
        getMedia(el);
    }

    function getMedia(el) {
        media_type = 'video';
        switch(media_type) {
            case 'image':
                /*** do some stuff ***/
                load_image();
                break;
            case 'video':
                /*** do some stuff ***/
                load_video();
                break;
        }
    }

    function load_video() {
        el.on('removeVideo',function() {
            /*** do some stuff ***/
        });
    }

    function load_image() {
        el.on('removeVideo',function() {
            /*** do some stuff ***/
        });
    }

    /*** need to be an event that I can trigger and detect when it's finish ***/
    function removeVideo() {
        /*** just for the example ***/
        if ($('iframe').length > 0) {
            $('iframe').attr('src','').load(function(){
                $('iframe').remove();
            });
        } else {
            $('img').remove();
        }
    }

    $(document).on('click touchend',next_prev, function() {
        el.on('removeVideo',function() {
            getMedia();
        });
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click touchend',close, function() {
        el.on('removeVideo',function() {
            /*** do some stuff ***/
        });
        return false;
    });

    init();

};
```

What is the right way to create a custom event listener in a plugin. I don't knwo how to handle this and what is the right way to create it.

Answer (score 1):

See .bind() and .trigger() methods :

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
el.bind("removeVideo", function() {
  // what to do when removeVideo is triggered
});
```

then you can trigger the event :

```
el.trigger("removeVideo");
```

**EDIT :**

Execute code after removeVideo is complete

**Solution 1:**

```
function removeVideo() {
    ...
    el.trigger("removeVideoComplete");
}

el.bind("removeVideoComplete", function() {
    // What you want
});
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
function removeVideo() {
    ...
    // simply do what you want ! Maybe call a function ? 
}
```

**Solution 3 :**

```
function removeVideo(callback) {
    ...
    callback(el);
}

...
var callback = function(el) {
    // what you want
}
removeVideo(callback);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this kind of principle seems to be synchrone and I need something that wait an asynchronous task is completed like .load(). May aim is to execute a code only when removeVideo is complete. It's not the case with your method...